# How can I increase memory of docker-machine vm from commandline?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I using Docker for Mac. (this is not Docker toolbox)
Is there a way to increase the memory of docker-machine from the command line?

In Docker toolbox (this is not Docker for Mac), increasing memory can like below commands. But I don't know how I can I do the same thing on docker for mac.

```
  docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 # increase memory to 2GB on virtual box machine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The command line `pinata` has been removed from latest native docker beta version](https://forums.docker.com/t/pinata-missing-in-latest-mac-beta-1-11-2-beta15/15541). You can't change docker memory via command now.

So after you installed native docker for mac, you should see a new icon on the top, click it, choice `preferences`, `advanced` . You should easily adjust the memory and CPUs.

[image]